# set JAVA_HOME in windows but "ant build" still fails

Tags: windows-7, windows, java, environment-variables

I've set `JAVA_HOME` in my Windows environment preferences:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20
```

However whenever I try to run ant build I get the following:

> Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
>   It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6"

I think the registry key `JAVASOFT` is interfering with my environment variable, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to copy the `Tools.jar` file from the `jdk/lib` folder to the `jre/lib` folder.

Comment: > I needed to copy the Tools.jar file from the jdk/lib folder to the
> jre/lib folder. Nice , it works !!! but just I want to know why ? why this does it work ?

Answer (score 2):

`JAVA_HOME` should be set to `C:\Program Files\Java` in the Command Prompt. You can do this with the following:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java
```

This will then look for the most current jdk, lib, jre installed on your system.

Answer (score 1):

OK, guys, for Windows 7 it needs the `JAVA_HOME` as a Windows Environmental Variable, I've also added `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\` and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin` to PATH, restarted Eclipse, now it works

Also - when `javac` refers to java classes from the JDK, it needs the main SDK folder, not the bin, the bin is only for the `javac.exe`, while the main folder has \include\ and other stuff necessary for compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Does seting your `PATH` variable to include your `JAVA_HOME` help?

```
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
```