# JAVA_HOME set on WINDOWS 10, but still get an error while using ANT build script

Tags: windows-10, java, environment-variables

Please do not mark this as a duplicate of [set JAVA_HOME in windows but "ant build" still fails](https://superuser.com/questions/148899/set-java-home-in-windows-but-ant-build-still-fails)

First and foremost, none of the solutions provided in the above question works to my situation with WINDOWS 10.

I have set JAVA_HOME environmental variable on WINDOWS 10 environment, but still unable to use the already set variable through an ANT script. Always get an error that JAVA_HOME environmental variable is not set.

Please check the following screenshot to gain more details about the issue that I'm facing with Java 8 and WINDOWS 10.

[image]

Comment: Your PATH variable appears to be far to long.  Shorten each instance of say Program Files to its shorten version.

Comment: Changed it to no avail!

Comment: Thanks for the help though, I have a workaround that's working. I'm setting the variable via a batch file before the ANT script executes